# How to extract hovered links from a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I have set up this [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K1SCSIsORsBnWP1X2n4HiOJ7ss6NkgWx8df02CfZi2E/edit?usp=sharing).

Can someone please help me extract the URL?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- add this script to your spreadsheet and then use this custom formula: **`=URL(A1)`**

  ```
  function URL(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
  var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
  throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
  var row = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
    var url = formulas[i][j].match(/=hyperlink\("([^"]+)"/i);
    row.push(url ? url[1] : '');
  }
  output.push(row);
  }
  return output
  }
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: This solution does not work for me when referencing any of the hyperlinked cells in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zf69Ry4Bttjjxo2EBlNgO9TayA8u-3Y7jNTGigefQE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

- or this indirect (shorter) one with a custom formula: **`=URL("A1")`**

  ```
  function URL(input) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input);
  var url = /"(.*?)"/.exec(range.getFormulaR1C1())[1];
  return url;
  }
  ```

  [image]

Comment: This solution does not work for me when referencing any of the hyperlinked cells in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zf69Ry4Bttjjxo2EBlNgO9TayA8u-3Y7jNTGigefQE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @adaaaam This can be done for links auto created by pasting them in or with the link button going to Tools -> Script editor and creating the following script:
`function GETLINK(input){ 
return spreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
}`
 
If cell A1 has the link you will need to reference it as `=GETLINK("A1")` 
That's not going to update dynamically if you have a lot of links so use `=GETLINK(cell("Address",A1))` to get around that.